# add computed remainingTime to each inserted row of a datagridview

Tags: vb.net

Hello on my project I am using vb and I have a datagridview binding with datasource. 
For example I have this columns name

StartTime- this show the time a job started

7:00 am
  4:30 pm

Hours- how long that job is going to run

30 minutes
  2 HOURS

I want to be able to add the compute remaining time to each row that is inserted into the datagridview.

I already have a column name remainingTime that is not binding to the datasource. How can i add the compute remainingtime to each row. Even when the user inserted a new row? I already calculate the remainingTime but it only do this for the first row.

In my Form Load I have

```
Dim myTime As Date
'RemainingTime
    Dim totalTime As Date = runningJobs_list.Rows(0).Cells(5).Value
    ' Dim totalTime As Date = runningJobs_list.Rows(0).Cells(5).Value
    myTime = totalTime.AddHours(runningJobs_list.Rows(0).Cells(6).Value)
    ' myTime = totalTime.AddHours(runningJobs_list.Rows(0).Cells(6).Value)
    Timer.Start()
```

this is my timer to do the countdown of reaming time

```
Private Sub Timer_Tick(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Timer.Tick
    'variable to compare two timespan
    Dim myspan As TimeSpan
    myspan = TimeSpan.Zero
    'decrease myTime to actual system time
    Dim remainingTime As TimeSpan = myTime.Subtract(Date.Now)

    'if the remaining time is less than zero then set red the entire row otherwise decrease timer
    If remainingTime < myspan Then
        runningJobs_list.Rows(0).DefaultCellStyle.BackColor = Color.Red
    Else
        runningJobs_list.Rows(0).Cells(8).Value = remainingTime

    End If
End Sub
```

Please could someone help me?

Answer (score 0):

You have to wrap that calculation into foreach loop which loops through all rows in grid (except last empty row. Check for rows IsNewRow status, or if Cells(0).Text is empty to validate is it empty or not...)

So this:

```
runningJobs_list.Rows(0).Cells(8).Value = ...
```

Should be something like this:

```
ForEach gridRow As DataGridRow in runningJobs_List.Rows
  gridRow.Cells(8).Value = ...<br />
Next
```

Comment: This works great it actually adds the remaining time for each row but because I declare totalTime As Date = runningJobs_list.Rows(0).Cells(5).Value
myTime = totalTime.AddHours(runningJobs_list.Rows(0).Cells(6).Value)
   Is actually computing the remainingTime from that first row in all the others rows. thanks a lot Mino I really appreciate your time

Comment: Did you got this fixed? Or do you still have a problem with that remainingTime?

If you want to still improve your code, you should make constant variables out of those column magic numbers (8,6,5). That would improve code readability nicely.

Comment: Mino this is what is happening the remainingTime is working but because my variable totalTime and myTime point to row(0) everytime I add a new row the remainingTime is the same for all the new rows.

Comment: Sorry for the last comment Mino, this is what is happening the remainingTime is working but because my variable totalTime and myTime point to row(0) everytime I add a new row the remainingTime is the same for all the new rows. totalTime myTime remainingTime
11:14           72  1:22
2:35           1 1:22 is taking the sum for the first row instead of this new row
Thanks