# How do I add a countdown timer to a datagridView object?

Tags: vb.net, datagridview, timer

I have a dataGridView object called dgvMonitor that will be used to display pending consultations that are required to be executed within a certain amount of time by a supervisor. The supervisor is given 24hours from the time he submitted an entry, into the program, to complete this task.

dgvMonitor is being filled with an SQL adaptor and once that is completed, I systematically add a new column (REMAINING_TIME) at index 0 or basically to the first column, in the DGV, after I fill the table.

Now, what I need to do is insert a timer, in each cell within column (REMAINING_TIME)

What I would like to do is use the date in column (DATE_SUBMITTED) which is located at index 12 or the 12th column, in the DGV, add 24hours to each date, in that column, and begin counting down. Once the counter is equal to 0, an event will be triggered.

I did some searching on here and all I could find was:

[How to create multiple timer handler in vb.net](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21229684/how-to-create-multiple-timer-handler-in-vb-net)

and

[add computed remainingTime to each inserted row of a datagridview](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20423381/add-computed-remainingtime-to-each-inserted-row-of-a-datagridview)

but I couldn't figure out how to apply their scenarios to fit my condition.

I would really appreciate anyone's help. If you need more information to go off of, please let me know and I will edit my question.

Thanks.

Comment: you dont actually need 1 timer per task or row (or cell) because they will all do the same thing.  I would use one LONG timer and in the tick event iterate the rows to update the time remaining.

Comment: The thing is, I don't even know the syntax to set this up. Could you help me?

Comment: In your SQL you should be able to create a Time_Remaining field calculated from (Date_SubMitted and Date.Now).  It would be positive or negative depending on if the time has lapsed.  Then if a plain old form timer was set for 2-3 minutes, just refresh the grid in the tick event and let SQL calc the new Time Remaining.

Comment: What you provided sounds like it would be better off implemented as a service, otherwise your application would have to be running all the time for this approach to make sense.. or at least long enough for an event to fire. There's a fairly simple way you could achieve similar functionality, though. Populate the database with the submitted time, calculate the timespan between current time and submitted date. Use that as the basis of your remaining time, populate the column, and begin the count down. Do this everytime your app restarts. Remove submitted time if the span is > 24 hrs.